# Google Natural Language Syntax Analysis

Tags: syntax, nlp, linguistics, google-cloud-nl

I'm not sure this is a coding issue/question.
I'm using Google's NLP to analyze the syntax of some sentences and I'm seeing some inconsistencies with Plural vs Singular designation. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding what I see as an inconsistency.

For example.

`The dolphins jump over the wall`

The word `dolphins` is labeled as `"SINGULAR"` and I was expecting `"PLURAL"`. I thought, maybe cause it's referring to the group, as ONE "school of fish"(although they are mammals)

So I tried `Crows`

`The crows jump over the wall`

`The crows are jumping over the wall`

Both of these return `crows` as `"SINGULAR"`, which I thought would be consistent since a group of `crows` is ONE "Murder of Crows"

Ok, fine then I tried `Cows` - a group of cows is ONE Herd

`The cows jump over the wall`

But in this sentence, the word `cows` is labeled `"PLURAL"`.

I'm no linguistics expert that maybe be a cause of my confusion.
Or is this "inconsistency" due to analyzing the sentence ONLY using the analyzeSyntax API without analyzing its sentiment or the entities?

This is the log for `The cows jump over the wall.`

```
{ theSentence: 'The cows jump over the wall.',
  theTags: [ 'DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT' ],
  theLabels: [ 'DET', 'NSUBJ', 'ROOT', 'PREP', 'DET', 'POBJ', 'P' ],
  theNumbers: 
   [ 'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'PLURAL',
     'SINGULAR',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'SINGULAR',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN' ]
```

This is the log for `The crows jump over the wall.`

```
{ theSentence: 'The crows jump over the wall.',
  theTags: [ 'DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT' ],
  theLabels: [ 'DET', 'NSUBJ', 'ROOT', 'PREP', 'DET', 'POBJ', 'P' ],
  theNumbers: 
   [ 'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'SINGULAR',
     'SINGULAR',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN',
     'SINGULAR',
     'NUMBER_UNKNOWN' ]
```

Update : I tried using `https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:analyzeSyntax` and I get the same results

Comment: A public issue tracker is created for the issue encountered on denoting a word's grammatical number. Feel free to add on more use cases where this issue is encountered. See issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/199097296.